# Chart Js doughnut chart breaking when handling great differences in values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i'm trying to create a custom looking doughnut chart using chart js.

[image]

my code ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5ud8ygo/)) works fine when the data values are close to each other
but when trying to handle data that has values far greater than other values, the chart breaks, [broken fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwgszyt3/)

[image]

i don't understand why is that happening, i think it has to do with arc spacing and radius but i don't know how to handle it and still make it look like what i need

code

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.8.0/dist/chart.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

```
let color1 = '#98A3CC';
let color2 = '#6475B2';
let hoverColor="#283F94";
var options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [3956745.7,5400,4086.06,50000],
      backgroundColor: [
      color1, color2, color1, color2],
      hoverBackgroundColor: new Array(4).fill(hoverColor),
    }]
  },
  options: {
    cutout: '90%',
    radius: '90%',
    //hover: {mode: null},
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    elements: {
      arc: {
        spacing: -50,
        borderRadius: 15
      }
    }
  }
}
var chartInstance = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), options);
```

Answer (score -2):

The `spacing: -50` property is causing this, as the spacing is negative the tip of the bar overlaps at the end of the next bar, when you place a bar with a value much higher than the others, it overlaps all the others. We can better observe the behavior by removing the `border-radius`:

[image]

So the solution is to adjust the value of the `spacing` property, in case any value of your data array is too much higher than the others, as we can see:

[image]

Comment: but i'm required to have that spacing, removing it is no option